# Howto inject AngularJS controller with lots of dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test one of my controllers. My Problem is that the created `$LoginController` object is always an empty object and instead my methods are all on the scope object. Then when I want to test the 
`hasError` function, I get a message:

*TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$route.current.params')*

Here is my test:

```
describe('login', function () {
        var $LoginController = null, $scope, $route, $location, $httpBackend;
        beforeEach(module('common.base64'));
        beforeEach(module('myapp.user'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $controller, $rootScope,
                                    _$location_, _$timeout_, _$route_, _Base64_)
        {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $route = _$route_;
            $location = _$location_;
            $LoginController = $controller('LoginController', {
                $scope : $scope, $http: $httpBackend, $location: _$location_,
                $timeout: _$timeout_, $route: _$route_, Base64: _Base64_}
            );
            console.log($LoginController); // <-- Log: {}
            console.log($scope);           // <-- Log: { <lots of stuff> }
        }));

        describe('LoginController', function() {
            it('should have been injected', inject(function () {
                    expect($LoginController).toBeTruthy();
                }
            ));
        });

        describe('hasError', function () {
                it('should return error', inject(function () {
                        $location.url('/login?loginError=true');

                        expect($scope.hasError).toBeTruthy();          
                                   // ^-- hasError is defined!
                        expect($LoginController.hasError).toBeTruthy();
                        //                      ^-- hasError is undefined! 
                    }
                ));
            }
        );
    }
);
```

In my LoginController the `hasError` function is defined like this:

```
    $scope.hasError = function () {
        if($route.current.params) {
            if ($route.current.params['loginError']) {
                return "error";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return "";
    };
```

Which I then inject into an elements class attribute. So which piece of my code is wrong, the controller, or the test?

Comment: The test. Why would there be a hasError method on the controller? hasError is a method of the scope, as the code of the controller shows. Note that you don't need to inject all the services that you don't use in the test, like Base64, $route and $timeout.

Comment: Would it be a better practice to assign the functions to `this` and then set `$scope.LoginController = this`?

Comment: Some people do that. I personnally don't see the advantage. `this` handling is a nightmare in JavaScript, and the view would have to use LoginController.foo() everywhere instead of simply foo().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is.

Since you are not using any routing in your test here, there will not be a current route to pull from.

You can explicitly set this up if you need to

```
_$route_.current = {
  params: {
    loginError: 12345
  }
};
```

`$location` and several other things all get swapped out with mocks if you are using the `ng-mock` module... which it appears you are.

So changing the `$location` isn't going to trigger a route change.

A better solution would be to change your controller to use the [`$routeParams`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams) dependency instead of accessing the current route itself. This way you can just pass that in during your test creation.

```
if($routeParams && $routeParams.loginError) {
   return "error";
}

return "";
```

And then in your tests, you can simply pass in the `$routeParams`

```
$LoginController = $controller('LoginController', {
  $scope : $scope, $http: $httpBackend, $location: _$location_,
  $timeout: _$timeout_, 

  // Mock out $routeParams here:
  $routeParams: {loginError: 'blah' }, 

  Base64: _Base64_}
);
```